# How to remove abnormalities from the Green vegetation fraction

Tags: qgis

Study area was clipped by using the shape file from Band 3 and Band 4. First, Band 3 and Band 4 were converted to at-satellite brightness temperature by using the built-in function in semi-automated tool in QGIS (semi-automatic classification plug-in).
NDVI was calculated by b4-b3/b4+b3 in landsat 5 images, the range of NDVI was 0.0968299 - 0.433846. 
Green Vegetation fraction were also needed to examine the role of vegetation in mix land cover that was derived from the equation:

> `GVF = NDVI - NDVImin / NDVImax - NDVImin`

but the problem here was as you would see the range of the fraction is -0.631684 - -0.0011024) that is due to some abnormalities in the data that don't know how to remove it. Is there something wrong in "NDVI" values as there is no data values (no data values = -3.4020 + 38) by seeing the properties of image in QGIS.
I have taken the NDVImin and NDVImax as 0.0968299 and 0.433846 respectively but literature has shown that the values 0.05 and 0.70 as NDVI threshold values that were derived by global Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer (AVHRR) 10-day composite data (Zeng et al. 2000).

Comment: This question seems to have been posted on Meta GIS by accident so I have migrated it to Main.

Comment: It looks like your no data value is affecting the calculation. You need to make sure the no data values are not included in the calculation. Need more information about your problem, data, and calculation method to provide a better answer

Answer (score 3):

Given the forumla:

> GVF = (x - min) / (max - min)

(Notice the brackets.) It is impossible for the values to be outside the range 0 - 1 for all values of x between min and max, which by definition it is. In fact, it should occupy the full range from 0 - 1. So we can conclude that either your min and max values aren't representative of the actual range of values in the image (e.g. if you used the display min and max values used to scale the palette rather than the actual data min and max) or else that there was a mistake in the form of the equation when you entered it. Solving for x, we get:

> x = GVF * (max - min) + min

Substituting in your minimum and maximum output values (-0.631684 and -0.0011024) we get a range of input values from -0.116057778 to 0.096458373. You'll notice that that upper range value is actually within three significant digits of your stated minimum value. (Coincidence? Possibly.) However, a range of NDVI values in an image from -0.116057778 to 0.096458373 does seem unlikely and you can confirm if this is the case by performing a histogram analysis on the image. It is much more probable to me that you simply had mixed up the equation slightly. Was it in the Raster Calculator that you performed this analysis? Given you dropped out the brackets in the equation in your question, I explored various combinations of missing brackets and wasn't able to come up with a form that would replicate your output range. I did find that the equation:

> OUT = (x - max) / (max + min)

for your input min value (0.0968299) resulted in the output value -0.635069541, which is very similar to your stated output minimum value. Unfortunately it won't give you your output max value, so that wasn't it...but it's likely some similarly mis-typed equation resulting from substituting + for - or leaving out a bracket here or there.

Note that the error is unlikely to be the result of a NoData value, as has been suggested, since 1) NoData values are generally very large negative values that would result in an output far outside the small negative values found in your output range, and 2) NoData values should really be ignored by any GIS that utilizes the construct.

Comment: I am following the research paper [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mPXisj_Q_ZRXlVNGJiZ1NZZFE/view?usp=sharing)_itlic_ **bold** 'code' and equatin 8 and want to make the graph as in figure 4 in this paper.

Comment: Very nicely detailed answer! I'm always surprised to see what various analytics can be applied to rasters.

Comment: @WaseemAli Yes, eq. 8 is equivalent to my first equation, i.e. the brackets are implied in the two-line form of the equation. You must perform the two subtractions before the division. Nonetheless, you still could not use this equation and get values in the range -0.63 to -0.001. Either your min and max values are incorrect or your usage of the equation was incorrect. I'd just double check both and see where you went wrong. These kinds of mistakes happen all the time during an analysis ;)

Comment: @WhiteboxDev, May be I was unable to explain of my question, I have derived NDVI map of same area of years 1992, 1998, 2002, 2010 but the ranges of every years representing 0-0.33, 0-0.45, 0-0.33, 0-.32, 0-0.30 respectively are different, how can I make them normalize into the same range so that I could see the difference of each successive images.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev. I have append some information in my another post, you can view it the data and my requirement there please.[link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119589/qgis-2-4-0-chugiak-how-to-produce-raster-colour-map)

Comment: @WhiteboxDev. I realized after your detailed reply that i was using display min and max value used to scale the palette rather than the actual range of image data. I need a little more help to how should i scale them accordingly so that i could make the graph as Hu and Jia did in figure 4 to see the relative change of each successive images.[paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/enhanced/doi/10.1002/joc.1984).

Comment: @WaseemAli If you have a variable that ranges from Xmin to Xmax and and you want to rescale it to the range Ymin to Ymax then for any member of X calculate the output Y as Y = Ymin + (X - Xmin) / (Xmax - Xmin) * (Ymax - Ymin)   This is the general formula for a linear rescaling.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev. please share any tutorial or book material to understand this. Did you read the research paper i have attached? Actually author have chosen the NDVI threshold to derive the GVF as mentioned in 2.3 section (min 0.05 and max 0.70) and this is problem how to chose that range for my study area. How these fractional values be presented onto the colour map as in Figure 4. Should I have to rescale these float values to integer values into 256 bit to represent the colour palette Or float values can also be displayed in arcGIS 10? I was actually confused to solve this matter.

Comment: @WaseemAli Your raw range of values will always be different than theirs (without rescaling) because you're dealing with a different landscape. Even in the same landscape the NDVI will differ through time. I don't think that you should expect your range to be the same as theirs.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev. So how could i expect these ranges in my data set. Is there any clue to deal with such matter.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev. With reference to your detailed answer, I have resolved little problem but still there is another problem to be resolved. I have calculated the ndvi values of 5 successive images detail [detail on another post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/120589/36828). I need your help to scale the palette. I don't understand how to fix the palette to see the relative change in successive imagery of green vegetation fraction. I have also attached the paper there to whom I am following.