# Stretching (rescaling) Raster (NDVI) Values between -1 and 1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, landsat, ndvi, stretch

I am trying to equalize NDVI values for the same area temporally. For example 2014 LS8 NDVI values between -.12 and .007 while 2011 LS5 values between -.33 and.77. I would like to equalize each raster values between -1 and 1 so it is more comparable.

Is there a way of doing this in ArcGIS 10?

[image]

If I use reclassify it creates 9 classes values between 1-9.

Can I use these classes temporally to compare NDVI for consecutive years?

My ultimate goal is measuring vegetation growth between 1991-2016 for different watersheds. I am planning to use cumulative NDVIs for each watershed. 
[image]

Comment: How about using `Raster Calculator`? This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192595/normalizing-raster-using-raster-calculator-in-arcgis-10-3-1) can be helpful. Your case will be `(("raster" - "raster".minimum) * 2 / ("raster".maximum - "raster".minimum)) - 1`

Comment: I think your approach is somewhat flawed since the reflectance values that you get from LANDSAT are dependent upon many climatic and atmospheric variables. If you are going to use this for viewing purposes, say a timeline to show veg cover loss, the direct scaling approach (min-max normalisation) advised by @Kazuhito may help. But if you are going to quantify change, I advise being cautious.

Comment: Thank you @Kazuhito I have tried raster calculator but it gave syntax error. I believe reclassify will accommodate what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thank you @fatih_dur, That's right I am trying to quantify vegetation growth. I am not trying to precise measurement but rather basic-intermediate classification. For example, 5 classes; barren, grass, bush, small trees and canopy, Would it be still a problem ?

Comment: Have a look at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52502/how-to-represent-trend-over-time, https://geonet.esri.com/thread/44291, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120589/how-to-normalize-or-rescale-the-ndvi-raster-image

Comment: @fatih_dur I have checked that before. I think I will use LandSat Higher data because I do not have ENVI and do not have much experience with gis. Moreover, higher Land Sat data should have better accuracy according to this research https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2015/01/landsat-8-surface-reflectance.html Thank you!